# Joining of CompletableFutures

Tags: java, completable-future

I've been working with CompletableFuture lately, trying to parallelize long lasting IO operations. I have to wait for everything to complete before I return, so I've used both

`CompletableFuture.allOf().join()`
and 
`stream().map(CompletableFuture::join)`

to enforce this. However, looking at the logs, I've had the impression that allOf().join is faster. I've played around with a test to see. The output in the end always show a higher time spent for stream join. One thing I've seen is that if I skip System.out.println() in CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(), the difference is less.

A typical output from the test as it is below:
`streamJoin: 3196 ms, allof: 3055 ms`

Is allOf().join(), and collecting afterwards the fastest way, or is my test flawed?

```java
package com.oyvind.completablefutures;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CompletableFutureTest {

    @Test
    public void joinPerformanceTest() throws Exception{

        // stream join
        long startStreamJoin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> result1 = listOfCompletableFutures("stream", Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100))
                .stream()
                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());// trigger execution
        long spentTimeStreamJoin = System.currentTimeMillis() - startStreamJoin;

        // allOf() join
        long startAllOf = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> completableFutures = listOfCompletableFutures("allOf", Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100));
        CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
        List<Integer> result2 = completableFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
        long spentTimeAllOf = System.currentTimeMillis() - startAllOf;

        log("streamJoin: %s ms, allof: %s ms", spentTimeStreamJoin, spentTimeAllOf);
    }

    private List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> listOfCompletableFutures(String name, Executor executor) {

        return IntStream.range(1, 1000)
                .boxed()
                .map(
                        i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                                () -> logAndSleepFor1Second(name),
                                executor
                        )
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private int logAndSleepFor1Second(String name) {
        log("Starting %s: %s", name, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private void log(String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + ": " + String.format(format, args));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use jmh to benchmark it. Otherwise, I would at least run them each multiple times, throw away the outliers, and calculate the average.

Comment: Using jmh (Java Micro-benchmarking Harness) is probably the best idea.

Comment: Tried to loop it 200 times each: avg streamJoin: 505 ms, allof: 504 ms. When running it once it showed consistent higher values for stream join, but avg is the same when running it multiple times. Have no idea why though.

Comment: Looks like the typical case of the first operation being slower than the second.